# Typescript provides error on react key property - Property 'key' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following code gives me the error `TS2322: Type '{ key: string; item: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ item: any; }'.   Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ item: any; }'.`

```
function Foo() {
    const myThings = ["hi", "bye"]
    return myThings.map((thing) => {
        return <Bar key={thing} item={thing} />
    })
}
function Bar({item}) {
    return <div>{item}</div>
}
```

How do I tell typescript that key is a property expected by react?

I'm using create-react-app and `"jsx": "react-jsx",` is the jsx setting in my tsconfig

Comment: Add another prop called `key` to `Bar` component

Comment: key is an inbuilt property in react that can't be passed to your own components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not have `@types/react` installed which caused WebStorm to give me the error.

Run `npm i -D @types/react`.

Comment: for VS Code users, follow the above steps and RELOAD the window!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this

```
const Foo = () => {
    const myThings = ["hi", "bye"]
    return myThings.map((thing) => {
        return <Bar key={thing} item={thing} />
    })
}

interface BarProps {
  key: string
  item: string
}

const Bar: React.FC<BarProps> = ({key, item}) => {
    return <div>{item}</div>
}
```